# AttributeError Exception raised when trying to bulk delete items in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to bulk delete all of the comments on a dev instance of my Django website and Django is raising an AttributeException.

I've got the following code on a python prompt:

```
>>> from django.contrib.comments.models import Comment
>>> Comment.objects.all().delete()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jeff/.virtualenvs/osl_main-website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 441, in delete
    obj._collect_sub_objects(seen_objs)
  File "/home/jeff/.virtualenvs/osl_main-website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 569, in _collect_sub_objects
    sub_obj._collect_sub_objects(seen_objs, self, related.field.null)
  File "/home/jeff/.virtualenvs/osl_main-website/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 585, in _collect_sub_objects
    delete_qs = rel_descriptor.delete_manager(self).all()
AttributeError: 'ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor' object has no attribute 'delete_manager'
```

I'm not sure as to why the delete statement is not working. Can anyone help me with why this isn't working and what I can do to fix it?

**Additional details about my models:**

I have another model called `OslComment` that inherits from `Comment`. I also have a `Vote` model that points to entries in `OslComment`.

**BaseCommentAbstractModel**

```
class BaseCommentAbstractModel(models.Model):
    """
    An abstract base class that any custom comment models probably should
    subclass.
    """

    # Content-object field
    content_type   = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
            verbose_name=_('content type'),
            related_name="content_type_set_for_%(class)s")
    object_pk      = models.TextField(_('object ID'))
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey(ct_field="content_type", fk_field="object_pk")

    # Metadata about the comment
    site        = models.ForeignKey(Site)
```

**Comment**

```
class Comment(BaseCommentAbstractModel):
    """
    A user comment about some object.
    """

    # Who posted this comment? If ``user`` is set then it was an authenticated
    # user; otherwise at least user_name should have been set and the comment
    # was posted by a non-authenticated user.
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=_('user'),
                    blank=True, null=True, related_name="%(class)s_comments")
    user_name   = models.CharField(_("user's name"), max_length=50, blank=True)
    user_email  = models.EmailField(_("user's email address"), blank=True)
    user_url    = models.URLField(_("user's URL"), blank=True)

    comment = models.TextField(_('comment'), max_length=COMMENT_MAX_LENGTH)

    # Metadata about the comment
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(_('date/time submitted'), default=None)
    ip_address  = models.IPAddressField(_('IP address'), blank=True, null=True)
    is_public   = models.BooleanField(_('is public'), default=True,
                    help_text=_('Uncheck this box to make the comment effectively ' \
                                'disappear from the site.'))
    is_removed  = models.BooleanField(_('is removed'), default=False,
                    help_text=_('Check this box if the comment is inappropriate. ' \
                                'A "This comment has been removed" message will ' \
                                'be displayed instead.'))
```

**OslComment**

```
class OslComment(Comment):
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, blank=True, null=True, related_name='parent_comment')
    inline_to_object = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    edit_timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    transformed_comment = models.TextField(editable=False)
    is_deleted_by_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**Vote**

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    """
    A vote on an object by a User.
    """
    user         = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id    = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object       = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    vote         = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=SCORES)
```

**Misc information:**

Python Version: 2.6.5
Operating System: Linux Mint 9 (Linux 2.6.32-21-generic)
Django: 1.2
Database driver: postgresql_psycopg2 (2.2.1)

Comment: Does any other model depend on the `Comment` model?  What ForeignKey attributes refer to Comments? I'm guessing your database has more the just the `Comment` model.

Comment: @S.Lott that's true, I've got a model that inherits from the `Comment` model to add a few extra fields and I'm using `django-voting`'s `Vote` table which has a few entries pointing to the inheriting model. Doesn't Django do a `CASCADE DELETE` in this situation?

Comment: @jeff charles: "Doesn't Django do a CASCADE DELETE in this situation?"  Why would it?  Where did you read that in the documentation?  What gave you the idea it did that?

Comment: @S.Lott: for the first @: this line in the docs gave me that idea: "When Django deletes an object, it emulates the behavior of the SQL constraint ON DELETE CASCADE -- in other words, any objects which had foreign keys pointing at the object to be deleted will be deleted along with it." <http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries-delete>

Comment: @.Lott: for the second @: I didn't think the information was relevant at the time I posted the question. I have since updated the question.

Comment: @jeff charles: Which database driver are you using in your `settings`?

Comment: @Jeff charles: Please don't comment.  Please **update**.  What version of Django are you using?  And what version of Python?  Please don't comment.  Please **update** the question.  And... don't add "Edit" all over the place, Stackoverflow keeps a complete change log.  Just make your question as complete as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Edited: Originally I thought you couldn't do delete() on a QuerySet and was going to recommend you iterate over the items, but apparently you can do bulk deletes like that.  Trying to iterate over the QuerySet might give you a better clue as to what's wrong, though.

Comment: Forgot this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/instances/#deleting-objects

Comment: Iterating over the QuerySet doesn't raise any exceptions and seems to work as I'd expect it to

Comment: Sorry, iterating w/o deleting appears to work as expected (will try w/ deleting tomorrow morning)

Comment: Iterating while deleting raises the same exception as trying to bulk delete

Comment: I have to agree that it seems to have something to do with the process for deleting related model objects.  I'll let you know if I think of anything more specific.  It might help if you updated your question with snippets from your model file.